# Scalar UDF expression table-troubleshoot

Tags: user-defined-functions

Why calling return me:
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'udf_string'.
When call look like this:

```
select * 
from [database].[udf_string]('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', ' ', 3)
```

UDF code look like this:

```
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_string]
(
    @start_str varchar(130),
    @split_str varchar(130),
    @element_index int
)
RETURNS  varchar(130)
AS
BEGIN
declare @final_str varchar(130)

        select @final_str = concat_ws('',a_split.t_val ,'')
        from ( 
        SELECT value as t_val , 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS str_num 
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@start_str, @split_str)
        ) a_split 
        where a_split.str_num = @element_index
        return @final_str

 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, query should be look like:

```
select [database].[udf_string]('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', ' ', 3)
```

Because this is not table function.